# mottie tablesorter, sticky header spacing with twitter bootstrap nav bar at top

Tags: tablesorter

With twitter bootstrap nav bar being sticky as well, it seems that when user scrolls down, the nav bar overlaps on top of the first row (column title) portion of the sticky header.  Is there a way to push the sticky header down by a row so that it can fall below the bootstrap sticky nav bar as you are scrolling?

Comment: Just found the answer! There's an option: stickyHeaders_offset.  I used it and it works perfectly!

Comment: You should add your answer below and select it so we all know this question has been answered. I'll even upvote it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need these steps to achieve that (because of the tablesorter scrolling mechanism):

OFFSET = number of pixels to offset from the top. In your case = the height of the sticky twitter bar

Add a widget option with your desire OFFSET (=integer, #pixels) from the top:

```
$(‘table’).tablesorter({
  widgets: [stickyHeaders'],
  widgetOptions: {
  stickyHeaders_offset: OFFSET 
  }
});
```

In my [post](http://morkrispil.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/tablesorter-stickyheaders-allowing-html-header) I mention a "divHeader", but in your case you already have the twitter bar - see if you need any of these CSS as well, in case your twitter bar doesn't cover it all

```
#divHeader
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: OFFSETpx;
  width: 100%; //to cover all the rows scrolling in the back…
  background-color: White; //to cover all the rows scrolling in the back…
}
```

Add this CSS to your main div containing your table:

```
margin-top: OFFSETpx;
```

This way you’ll achieve smooth table sticky-enabled scrolling, with your sticky twitter bar

You can see my complete [post](http://morkrispil.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/tablesorter-stickyheaders-allowing-html-header) about it.

BTW, mottie, great job with the tablesorter! I believe your fork is pretty much the main one in use today :)